# Importing .xls files into database Jboss

Tags: java, mysql, jboss7.x

I am building a web application with JBoss 7. I will be getting datasets in .xls format that I want to drop into a folder on the server. In turn, these .xls files will be imported into the database in jboss. There should be some kind of auto detection in the folder so that when a .xls file is dropped in there it is automatically imported into the database. Please can someone advise me what tools / technologies are available for importing .xls files into the database in JBoss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide this into several tasks:

- Deciding of you really want to do this directly inside JBoss with a `Service` or with a external program connecting to a `SessionBean`.
- Detecting changes of the directory (e.g. with Java7 and the [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)
- Reading the XLS files (e.g. with [Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents](http://poi.apache.org)
- Mapping the content of the XLS files to entities of your domain model and store them into the DB.